# Silverlight 3.0: Can't add references beyond v2

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, reference

I wanted to add System.Data.Linq to my Silverlight 3.0 app, but the only references that are available to me are listed as version 2.0.50727 or lower. Shouldn't I have access to more than that?

In my project's properties, my Target Silverlight Version is set to "Silverlight 3.0" (the only option), and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

Is this expected behavior, or should I be able to add that reference, and more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `System.Data.Linq` in Siverlight, this dll would make no sense in the sandboxed client-side silverlight runtime.  Hence no such silverlight dll exists.  What you probably need to be looking into is Entity Framework on the server plus WCF to access the data from Silverlight.

For reasons best known by Microsoft all the standard Silverlight dlls have the 2.0.5.0 version numbers even the new ones added to the Silverlight 3 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This is the version number of the controls in Silverlight 3. It confused me at first. Also it's `System.Linq` in Silverlight and should be included by default when you create a new project.

Silverlight 4 is a separate download to VS2010.

Comment: Does that mean I can't access System.Data.Linq, since it's not in that list?